# Is the Minkowski sum of two connected sets also connected?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sumset

Is the Minkowski sum of two connected sets, $A+B$, also connected?

Can I use translation mapping here?

Comment: As a subset of R^n. What happened when we change R^n to general metric and topological space. I think this property may not preserve.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

$A+B$ is the image of $A\times B$ under the continuous map $(x,y)\mapsto x+y.$

A product of connected spaces is connected, and a continuous image of a connected space is connected.